# AWS cloudwatch sending two alert notifications for a single event

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm using AWS cloudwatch to monitor and send alerts if memory usage exceeding 90%. This has been configured with SNS topic to deliver alert notification.

Whenever the memory usage crossing 90% means use to get 2 alert message for this single event and not sure why the duplicate mail getting triggered.

Alarm conditions,

```
Metric name : MemoryUsed
Threshold: MemoryUsed > 14446883635 for 10 datapoints within 15 minutes
Statistic : Maximum
Period: 1 minute
Datapoints to alarm: 10 out of 15
Missing data treatment: Treat missing data as missing
Percentiles with low samples: evaluate
```

Comment: Where are the screenshots?

Comment: Sorry, unable to attach it. updated alarm conditions